# How to pull out all tags by posts?

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot create a SQL query to get all the tags for the post

I have three tables: `posts`, `tags`, `post_tag`.

```
posts
+----+----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| id | title                                  | text                                                  | author |
+----+----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | Porridge ? a perfect breakfast?        | Porridge. It doesn?t have a very tasty name, does ... | admin  |
|  2 | Searching: film review                 | How much should we believe what we see online?  Th... | admin  |
|  3 | What makes 'Black Panther' so special? | What makes 'Black Panther' so special?                | admin  |
+----+----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

```
tags
+----+------------------+-------------+
| id | title            | description |
+----+------------------+-------------+
|  1 | food             |             |
|  2 | meals            |             |
|  3 | films            |             |
|  4 | film review      |             |
|  5 | social media     |             |
|  6 | internet         |             |
|  7 | superheroes      |             |
|  8 | around the world |             |
+----+------------------+-------------+
```

```
post_tag
+----+---------+--------+
| id | post_id | tag_id |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 |
|  2 |       1 |      2 |
|  3 |       2 |      3 |
|  4 |       2 |      4 |
|  5 |       2 |      5 |
|  6 |       2 |      6 |
|  7 |       3 |      3 |
|  8 |       3 |      4 |
|  9 |       3 |      7 |
| 10 |       3 |      8 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

The post_tag table contains the post id and id tag.
 Many-to-many relationships.

I need to pull out all tags belonging to the post. I have a post id.

Comment: This is waaaay too less information. Format your question, give more information.

Comment: select tags.title from post_tag left join tags on post_tag.tag_id = tags.id where post_tag.post_id = 1

Comment: Here is the answer: select * from `tags` inner join `post_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `post_tag`.`tag_id` where `post_tag`.`post_id` = {post_id}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand your question, you need to get all tags for a post. If that's the case, this is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM tags t
LEFT OUTER JOIN post_tag pt
  ON pt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE pt.id = {post_id}
```

Comment: There is no problem for which the above is a valid solution.

Comment: Here is the answer to my question select * from tags inner join post_tag on tags.id = post_tag.tag_id where post_tag.post_id = {post_id}